# Selenium can't find elements with dynamic IDs

Tags: selenium

I'm having a problem clicking an option selection in the following dropdown on the page:

http://www.lan.com/es_co/sitio_personas/index.html

[image]

When I run the code:

```
    By byCabinSelect = By.cssSelector("select[name=\"campoComboCabina\"]");
    List<WebElement> cabinSelects = driver.findElements( byCabinSelect );
    for (WebElement cabinSelect : cabinSelects) {
         List<WebElement> Elements = cabinSelect.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
         System.out.println( Misc.getElementData(cabinSelect));
         System.out.println( Misc.getElementData(Elements) );   
    }
```

I can see I have what seems to be the right selector but the element's options are marked as not visible:

```
tagName:         select
  id:           
  text:         
  innerHtml:    <option value="Y">Economy</option><option value="W">Premium Economy</option><option value="J">Premium Business</option>
  outerHtml:    <select name="campoComboCabina" class="" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"><option value="Y">Economy</option><option value="W">Premium Economy</option><option value="J">Premium Business</option></select>
  isDisplayed:  false
  isEnabled:    true
tagName:         option
  id:           
  text:         
  innerHtml:    Economy
  outerHtml:    <option value="Y">Economy</option>
  isDisplayed:  false
  isEnabled:    true
tagName:         option
  id:           
  text:         
  innerHtml:    Premium Economy
  outerHtml:    <option value="W">Premium Economy</option>
  isDisplayed:  false
  isEnabled:    true
tagName:         option
  id:           
  text:         
  innerHtml:    Premium Business
  outerHtml:    <option value="J">Premium Business</option>
  isDisplayed:  false
  isEnabled:    true
```

And so attempting to click the option:

```
cabinSelect.findElement( By.xpath("option[.='Economy']") )
           .click();
```

fails with:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

### Update

I've been examining this some more with Selenium IDE.  It appears that every time an item from the dropdown is selected it has a different id, of the form ui-selectmenu-item-*nnn*.  But, if I list all elements, immediately after dropping down list, the  using the selector

```
By.cssSelector("*[id^='ui-selectmenu-item-']")
```

the 3 I need are NOT in the list.  Selenium IDE suggests I could also use something like

```
//a[contains(text(),'Economy')]
```

to identify the element but generating a list using

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Economy')]")
```

also fails to return the element I need.

Can there exist elements that Selenium can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here this site seem use select2 to build dropdown, you couldnot use traditional method to select.

Here's the working script

```
    public class TestSelenium {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.lan.com/es_co/sitio_personas/index.html");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        driver.findElement(By.name("campoOrigen")).sendKeys("SGN");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'SGN')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("campoDestino")).sendKeys("BOG");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'BOG')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("campoFechaIda")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='22']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("campoFechaVuelta")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='28']")).click();
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'campoComboCabinas')]//span[@class='ui-selectmenu-status']"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'ui-selectmenu-open')]//a[text()='Premium Economy']")).click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfectly. Is @class, 'ui-selectmenu-open' is always the holder of selection options using select2?

Comment: not 100%, it depends on dev team's code. In general, I suggest we should double check the mechanism carefully to make sure right way selected.

Answer (score 0):

use the official way to select from ddl like so :

```
Select dropdownlist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("your-selector")));
dropdownlist.selectByVisibleText("Economy");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this gives the same error:

ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: ok , first click on ddl and then loop on this selector instead "ui-selectmenu-status" , and get the content of text , also check if the text = what you sent and click on it if true , sorry for the pseudo code :)

Comment: Not quite following what you're suggesting here Hasan.  Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Looks like it might be more complicated than this.  OP updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this code is working:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_selector"));
```

`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);`